# Insertar y Obtener ultimo ID de SQL Server y mostrar en C# Utilizo Dapper

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net, visual-studio-2017, dapper

[image]

Hola necesito ayuda! Quiero insertar y tambn poder obtener el ultimo ID que se ingreso, utilizo el framework dapper

Comment: hubiera ayudado que pusieras el codigo como texto en lugar de una imagen, pero por lo que muestras no es dapper lo que estas usando

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener un valor simple de una consulta puedes usar el `ExecuteScalar()` del objeto `SqlCommand`

Algo como esto

```
string connstring = "connection string";    
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connstring))  
{    
    cn.Open();    

    string sql = @"SELECT Max(Id)
                    FROM NombreTabla";    
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);    

    int MaxId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());    

    //resto codigo

}
```

Si es con `Dapper` es practicamente los mismo ya que tienes tambien el `ExecuteScalar<>()`

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connstring))  
{    
    cn.Open();    

    string sql = @"SELECT Max(Id)
                    FROM NombreTabla";    
    int MaxId = cn.ExecuteScalar<int>(sql);
    //resto codigo

}
```